# fixed-width and auto-width divs in one line

Tags: html, css

I have chat window where I want to put photo and message next to photo. Conversation window must be responsive and message div auto-adjustable to the screen. But I can't find any way to do this, because once message has few lines of text, it drops to the next line.

If I use table, I can't make fixed-width photo TD. If I use DIVS, I can't do auto-width message DIV :)

Here is JSFiddle with an example:
https://jsfiddle.net/s95tdcLw/3/

HTML:

```
<div class="receiver">
  <div class="receiverPhoto"></div>
  <div class="receiverMessage">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit
  </div>
</div>

<div class="receiver">
  <div class="receiverPhoto"></div>
  <div class="receiverMessage">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin et mauris eget est maximus condimentum nec a turpis.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="receiver">
  <div class="receiverPhoto"></div>
  <div class="receiverMessage">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin et mauris eget est maximus condimentum nec a turpis. Nulla nulla est, feugiat vitae posuere et, efficitur ac justo. Suspendisse pulvinar, urna quis vehicula malesuada, lorem lacus luctus odio,
    eu mattis nisi turpis vel lectus.
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.receiver {
  clear: both;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}

.receiverPhoto {
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.receiverMessage {
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  background: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave the `float` settings, use these instead:

```
.receiver {
  position: relative;
}

.receiverPhoto {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

.receiverMessage {
  margin-left: 45px;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s95tdcLw/4/)

Comment: I have a problem where photo is on the right side. I can't use right:0, because conversation div is inside of another div of maximum width:1000px, so it floats to right side of the window too much :)

Comment: Create a fiddle, I'll see what you can do

Comment: here it is! Sorry that I didn't catched it out from the beginning - https://jsfiddle.net/s95tdcLw/5/

Answer (score 1):

Your `.receiverMessage` element should not float and it should reserve left-margin space for the `.receiverPhoto` element.

```
.receiverMessage {
  /* should not float */
  width: auto;
  background: rgb(230, 230, 230);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 50px; /* reserve space of .receiverPhoto width */
  padding: 10px;
}
```

See the forked Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/092b077c/

---

In response to your comment how to make it work for the opposite...

I'd use the classes on the wrapping div elements to determine the message type. In my example I introduce a new class `.sender`. Now I create four selectors that determine whether the photo element floats left or right and whether the message element has left or right padding:

**New CSS:**

```
.sender .receiverPhoto {
  float: right;
}
.sender .receiverMessage {
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.receiver .receiverPhoto {
  float: left;
}
.receiver .receiverMessage {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="sender">
  <div class="receiverPhoto"></div>
  <div class="receiverMessage">...</div>
</div>
```

Now the `.receiverPhoto` and `.receiverMessage` styles do not need to declare margin or float.

See the updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/092b077c/1/

Comment: it works with version where is photo on the left, but I can't handle what to do when photo is in right.